# Recursive Function & Looping In Excel

Tags: excel, vba, recursion, circular-reference

I am looking for some guidance in looping through a function in Excel within a table without running into a circular reference error. I've spent quite some time trying out COUNTIF, MATCH, Essentially, I need to create a function/formula for the "Desired Date" column so that it takes value from the "Original Date" column and changes the value based on the following parameter:

- If a date in the **Original Date** column does not exist within the previous values of the **Desired Date** column, it will list the exact date. I've already solved this part with IF and COUNTIF functions.
- If a date in the **Original Date** column already exits within the previous values of the "Desired Date" column, it will add +1 day(s) until all the values within the **Desired Date** column have unique dates.

Here's what I would like the function to do:

Row 1 contains the original date value as 8/1, since no other values exist in the desired row column, it will return 8/1.

Row 2 contains the original date value as 8/1, but since row 1 of the desired date value already contains value 8/1, it will add +1 day so it becomes 8/2.

Row 3 contains the original date value as 8/1, but since row 1 & row 2 of the desired date contain the value, it will add +2 days, so it becomes 8/3.

Row 6 contains the original date value as 8/3, but since row 3 of the desired date contain the value, it will add +1 day so it becomes 8/4.

If at any given point a date within the original date changes, the values in desired dates should change accordingly by adding a variable amount of days until all values within the Desired Dates column are unique.

| Row | Original Dates | Desired Dates |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 8/1/2021 | 8/1/2021 |
| 2 | 8/1/2021 | 8/2/2021 |
| 3 | 8/1/2021 | 8/3/2021 |
| 4 | 8/12/2021 | 8/12/2021 |
| 5 | 8/12/2021 | 8/13/2021 |
| 6 | 8/3/2021 | 8/4/2021 |
| 7 | 8/4/2021 | 8/5/2021 |
| 8 | 8/3/2021 | 8/6/2021 |
| 9 | 8/13/2021 | 8/14/2021 |

I've spent well over 9 hours on this issue so any help at this point would be very much appreciated. I wouldn't mind using VBA but a function would be preferred for compatibility purposes.

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach might be to generate dates starting with the date in the first column but ignoring any dates that have already been used (countif>0), then pick the lowest of these:

```
=LET(maxdate,$D$2,
startdate,B2,
seq,SEQUENCE(maxdate-startdate,1,startdate),
MIN(IF(COUNTIF(E$1:E1,seq),maxdate,seq)))
```

[image]

or slightly shorter

```
=LET(maxdate,$D$2,
startdate,B2,
seq,SEQUENCE(maxdate-startdate,1,startdate),
MIN(IF(COUNTIF(E$1:E1,seq)=0,seq)))
```

If you don't have Excel 365, you can use Row instead of Sequence:

```
=MIN(IF(COUNTIF(E$1:E1,ROW(INDEX(A:A,B2):INDEX(A:A,$D$2)))=0,ROW(INDEX(A:A,B2):INDEX(A:A,$D$2))))
```

entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

**EDIT**

If you wanted to concatenate as in your comment, you wouldn't be able to use Min (because the values wouldn't be numeric) but you could use index/match to find the first available date for a particular person:

```
=LET(maxdate,$D$2,
startdate,A2,
name,B2,
seq,SEQUENCE(maxdate-startdate,1,startdate),
seqName,seq&name,
INDEX(seqName,MATCH(0,COUNTIF(H$1:H1,seqName),0)))
```

[image]

If you wanted to make the dates appear as a date rather than a number, you could wrap them in Text:

```
=LET(maxdate,$D$2,
startdate,A2,
name,B2,
seq,SEQUENCE(maxdate-startdate,1,startdate),
seqName,TEXT(seq,"mm/dd/yy")&name,
INDEX(seqName,MATCH(0,COUNTIF(H$1:H1,seqName),0)))
```

Comment: Hi thank you so much for your help! This has helped me tremendously. I appreciate you taking the time and effort to work through the solution. I had initially hoped to CONCAT a text with the date and use the function to look through previous concatenated values. However, I could not find a way to use the SEQUENCE function with CONCAT. Would a concatenation of text to each date be possible?

Comment: Following up on my initial comment, I was hoping to run something like this: https://ibb.co/ftYg0XC

What I was hoping to do is for each employee, it would run through the concatenated list and see if the concatenated record exists, and then it would add +1 day(s) to the date value and return a concatenated value. From there I can extract a desired date value. Any advice would be highly appreciated! Thank you again for taking your time to answer my original question.

Comment: You're welcome! I think it would be possible, maybe using countifs instead of countif, but I'm going to be out for the next 3 or 4 hours so won't be able to look at it properly till later.

Comment: Hi Tom, thank you so much for all your help! This formula worked perfectly! I don't know how to express how much this means to me. Thank you again for taking your time and helping out an Excel novice!